# Declaring and initializing array of class objects in Dafny

Tags: dafny

I am trying to create a simple class that stores an array of users, another class as demonstrated here:

```
include "User.dfy"

class EnrollmentStation {
    var x : array<User>;
    constructor() {
        x := new User[2];
    }
}
```

I am getting this error on var x's declaration:

```
Undeclared top-level type or type parameter: User (did you forget to qualify a name or declare a module import 'opened'?)
```

I cannot find anything in the documentation that details declaring and initializing object arrays. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the contents of User.dfy?

Comment: This isn't an issue with arrays: if you wrote `var u: User` you would get the same issue.  You're missing an `import` to give you access to the name `User`